# How to send emails with List<string>() using Send Grid mvc azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, azure, sendgrid

I was reading the Send Grid documentation, and below it states that in order to add emails of recipients, this is required:

```
    // Add multiple addresses to the To field.
List<String> recipients = new List<String>
{
    @"Jeff Smith <jeff@example.com>",
    @"Anna Lidman <anna@example.com>",
    @"Peter Saddow <peter@example.com>"
};

myMessage.AddTo(recipients);
```

Meanwhile in my code I have a list string with stored emails.

```
 emailing.find_email_send = new List<string>();
 emailing.find_email_send.Add("nick@hotmail.com");
 emailing.find_email_send.Add("John@hotmail.com");
 emailing.find_email_send.Add("Jack@hotmail.com");
```

How can I add this to recipients ? I tried using forloop:

```
recipients.Add(emailing.find_email_send[i]);
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the myMessage.AddTo method takes a List as a parameter and you already have your addresses in a List, then you don't need to do anything except:

```
myMessage.AddTo(emailing.find_email_send);
```

If you really want to add the addresses from your list to the recipients list it would be:

```
var recipients = new List<string>();
foreach (var address in emailing.find_email_send)
{
    recipients.Add(address);
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the help. Just one thing, do I have to put my List parameters as: 
"<nick@hotmail.com>" or "nick@hotmail.com"